# Integration with two complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

How can this integral be calculated? $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{n}(x+2)^{s-1}x^{z-1}dx$.

With $0<Re(s)<1$; $0<Re(z)<1$; $Im(s)\geq 1$, $Im(z)\geq 1$.
$n>1$

Comment: Use $x^z=e^{zln(x)}=x^{Re(z)}(cos(Im(z)ln(x))+isin(Im(z)ln(x))$ etc.  and compute real and imaginary parts separately.

Comment: @herb steinberg Maybe there is a way to replace the variable? What do you think?

Comment: Do you have a constraint on $n$?  Is $n$ real?  If so, is $n < -2$, $-2 < n < 0$, and/or $0 < n$?  Generically, you should try to transform this into an integral for the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

Comment: @Eric Towers I will try. Thank you.  Seems to be the right way.